# Swift IOS - How can I obtain permission to upload a document when testing on a device?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, file-upload, permissions

I am integrating a documentPicker into my IOS app. Selected files will be uploaded using Firebase Storage. I am getting this error when attempting to upload the file while testing the app on my iPhone:

```
Error uploading file: The file “file.pdf” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
```

On the other hand, am not getting this or any other error when testing using the simulator, and the error occurs whether I select a file from iCloud or on local storage.

Here is the code for picker:

```
struct DocumentPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

@Binding var filePath: URL?

func makeCoordinator() -> DocumentPicker.Coordinator {
    return DocumentPicker.Coordinator(parent1: self)
}

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
    let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.item"], in: .open)
    picker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    return picker
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: DocumentPicker.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) {
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    
    var parent: DocumentPicker
    
    init(parent1: DocumentPicker){
        parent = parent1
    }
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        // Here is where I get the path for the file to be uploaded
        parent.filePath = urls[0]
        print(urls[0].absoluteString)
    }
}
```

}

Here is the upload function, and where the error is caught:

```
do {
            let fileName = (PickedDocument?.lastPathComponent)!
            let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: PickedDocument!)
            let StorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(uid + "/" +  doc.documentID + "/" + fileName)
            StorageRef.putData(fileData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                guard let metadata = metadata else {
                    return
                }
                StorageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    guard let urlStr = url else{
                        completion(nil)
                        return
                    }
                    let urlFinal = (urlStr.absoluteString)
                    ShortenUrl(from: urlFinal) { result in
                        if (result != "") {
                            print("Short URL:")
                            print(result)
                            completion(result)
                        }
                        else {
                            completion(nil)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Error uploading file: " + error.localizedDescription)
            self.IsLoading = false
            return
        }
    }
```

Obviously there is some sort of permission that I need to request in order to be able to access and upload files on a physical iPhone, but am not sure how to get that? I have tried adding the following in `info.plist` but it still didn't work.

```
<key>NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription</key>
<string>To access device files for upload upon user request</string>
```

Comment: Since you have used `.open` the URL you receive is a security scoped resource; you need to work with it appropriately https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014451-CH2-SW3

Comment: How do you go from selecting a file with `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to uploading that file?  Where does a guy named 'PickedDocument' come from?

Comment: @ElTomato 'self.PickedDocument' is just a 'URL?' state variable. So I get the URL from the picker in 'didPickDocumentsAt' above and then I store it in that state variable.

Comment: Couple of things: Your question asks about uploading a file but that's not what the code does. Your code is converting local file to Data and attempting to putData. Why not just upload the file? Storage can handle a variety of file types; .jpg, .png. .pdf etc. Secondly which specific line is crashing? I am trying to determine if this is related to Firebase or if it's a file system issue. Oh, and PLEASE stick to standards; variables are always lower cased; upper case is reserved for Structs and classes; `PickedDocument` should be `pickedDocument` - `StorageRef` should be `storageRef`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out based on an answer I found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/ios/uidocumentviewcontroller-stopaccessingsecurityscopedresource/1250).

What I was doing is: I was storing a reference to the local file, which is a security scoped resource. Hence the permission error was thrown.

What I did to get around this: At the moment when the user picks the file, I will use `url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` to start accessing its content and make a copy of the file instead of holding its reference.

Here is the updated code for the picker `didPickDocumentsAt`:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard controller.documentPickerMode == .open, let url = urls.first, url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else { return }
        defer {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            }
        }
        
        do {
            let document = try Data(contentsOf: url.absoluteURL)
            parent.file = document
            parent.fileName = url.lastPathComponent
            print("File Selected: " + url.path)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error selecting file: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    }
```

And then my Storage upload function is:

```
func UploadFile(doc: DocumentReference, completion:@escaping((Bool?, String?) -> () )) {
    do {
        let StorageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child(self.User + "/" +  doc.documentID + "/" + fileName!)
        StorageReference.putData(file!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.alertMessage = error.localizedDescription
                self.showingAlert = true
                completion(false, nil)
            }
            else {
                StorageReference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        self.alertMessage = error.localizedDescription
                        self.showingAlert = true
                        completion(false, nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        ShortenUrl(from: url!.absoluteString) { result in
                            if (result != "") {
                                completion(true, result)
                            }
                            else {
                                completion(false, nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        self.alertMessage = "Error uploading file: " + error.localizedDescription
        self.showingAlert = true
        completion(false, nil)
    }
}
```